# download a radio show off a news website that invloves .tsSeg1-Frag files

Tags: download, audio-streaming

Using a stream software I got my grasp on the whole packets files that make the radio show I want to download from a news website.
The files are located at:

```
http://80.244.172.41/USER_HTTP_Proxy_interstream5_93995/SESSION_/HLSID_HDS_21076/ZiXi_params_end/109/201505/20150519-16.tsSeg1-Frag0
```

(This is the first file, it goes up to 180 or something).
How can I make it a one .mp3 file? Is there a script to make more automatic?
I would be very glad to make it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: VLC media player may be able to open and record the stream.

Answer (score 0):

There are some applications that can concatenate a file stream, but another option is to record the stream as it's being played, e.g. using [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/). To improve sound quality, use a tool such as [VB Cable virtual Audio Device](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/) for Windows or, for Linux, [Jack or VSound](http://alternativeto.net/software/vb-audio-cable/?platform=linux), which add a new input and a new output device to the sound control system.
[image: Sound CPL]

There are disadvantages, in that transfer speed is limited to the audio speed, and monitoring with a virtual cable requires a work-around. For some audio streams, though, it may be the *only* feasible way to download, and it works for *all* audio streams.